# How do you detect network connectivity loss on Nougat even if your app is not running?

Tags: android, networking, background-process, connectivity, android-jobscheduler

On APIs below Nougat, you can just declare a receiver in the manifest that subscribes to CONNECTIVITY_CHANGES. This allowed me to listen for network connectivity changes, whether the connectivity turned on or off, and allowed me to do tasks even if my app was not running.

On Nougat, this doesn't seem to be possible. I know that the JobScheduler on Nougat can be used to do certain tasks in the background if there is network connectivity, but there doesn't seem to be an option that listen for network connectivity loss.

In other words, I want the ability to hear when my phone has lost all connectivity (Wi-Fi, LTE etc.) and to do something in the background when this happens. Is this possible on Nougat?

Comment: Have you tried creating a `JobInfo` with `setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE)` and another with `setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)`?

Comment: you may want to tread carefully - changes to the cellular devices radio does occur very frequently - dont expect it to ever stop either this could keep the users phone very busy.

Comment: @JaredRummler NETWORK_TYPE_NONE doesn't do what you think it does. It basically means run this job no matter what kind of network connectivity you have rather than meaning: do this job only when there is no network

Comment: @GeorgeYang, ah, okay. This [library](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/pwittchen/reactivenetwork/library/network/observing/strategy) looks like it uses a `NetworkRequest` with `registerNetworkCallback`. Perhaps you could have a service always running with network callbacks. ¯_(⊙_ʖ⊙)_/¯

Comment: I think yuo can register a `BroadcastReciever` with manual registration. It will still work, only manifest registration started to fail.

Comment: Hi George, am facing the same problem.Can you give some idea how did you achieved, it would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use NetworkChangeReceiver

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "NetworkChangeReceiver";
private boolean isConnected = false;
Context mContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
    isNetworkAvailable(context);
    mContext=context;

}

public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    if (!isConnected) {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Now you are connected to Internet!");
                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.internet_available, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        isConnected = true;


                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "You are not connected to Internet!");
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.internet_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




    isConnected = false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @f.khantsis If this needs to happen in the background, without an activity open, where would you do this?

Comment: @the_gesslar use it inside your application class.